# Example configuration for Joins on Foreign Key with Spring-Kafka and Confluent Registry

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I already managed to make some Avro KStream joins with Spring Cloud Stream and now trying to use the new foreign key join between two Ktables with, I thought, simpler Spring-Kafka

Here is the configuration :

```
spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092
spring.kafka.streams.application-id=hubbit
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8081
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.key.serde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.value.serde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.deserialization.exception.handler=org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
spring.kafka.streams.properties.state.dir=/var/lib/kafka-streams
spring.kafka.streams.properties.auto-offset-reset=latest
ficexp.tools.topic.name=ficexp1.ficexp.tools
ficexp.tools_types.topic.name=ficexp1.ficexp.tools_types
ficexp.enriched_tools.topic.name=ficexp1.ficexp.enriched_tools
```

and my main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class StreamsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StreamsApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Value("${ficexp.tools.topic.name}")
    private String tools ;
    @Value("${ficexp.tools_types.topic.name}")
    private String tools_types ;
    @Value("${ficexp.enriched_tools.topic.name}")
    private String enriched_tools ;
    Function<ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Envelope,ficexp1.ficexp.tools_types.Key> foreignKeyExtractor =
            (ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Envelope x) -> {
                return ficexp1.ficexp.tools_types.Key.newBuilder().setId(x.getAfter().getToolsTypeId()).build();
            };
    public class EnrichedToolJoiner implements ValueJoiner<ficexp1.ficexp.tools_types.Envelope, ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Envelope, ficexp1.ficexp.tools.enriched>
    {
        @Override
        public ficexp1.ficexp.tools.enriched apply(ficexp1.ficexp.tools_types.Envelope tools_types,ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Envelope tools)
        {
            return ficexp1.ficexp.tools.enriched.newBuilder().
                    setId(tools.getAfter().getId())
                    .setLib(tools.getAfter().getLib())
                    .setValid(tools.getAfter().getValid())
                    .setToolsTypeId(tools.getAfter().getToolsTypeId())
                    .setTypelib(tools_types.getAfter().getLib())
                    .build();
        }
    }
    final EnrichedToolJoiner enrichedToolJoiner = new EnrichedToolJoiner();
    @Bean
    public KTable<ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Key, ficexp1.ficexp.tools.enriched> enriched_toolsTable(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {
        KTable<ficexp1.ficexp.tools_types.Key, ficexp1.ficexp.tools_types.Envelope> tools_typesTable = kStreamBuilder.table(tools_types);
        KTable<ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Key,ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Envelope > toolsTable = kStreamBuilder.table(tools);
        KTable<ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Key, ficexp1.ficexp.tools.enriched> enrichedToolTable = toolsTable.leftJoin(
                tools_typesTable,
                foreignKeyExtractor,
                (ValueJoiner) enrichedToolJoiner
        );
        return enrichedToolTable;
    }
}
```

(I know it is not finished) but it does not run. 
The consumer group is registered on Kafka broker
and that seems to be the only thing that works.

The error seems to be about Serde (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionWrapperSerde)

I'm quite lost, any clue ?

```
2020-02-25 13:45:50.181 ERROR 15496 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enriched_toolsTable' defined in ubx.hub.streams.StreamsApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable]: Factory method 'enriched_toolsTable' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-20200225.112934-316.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-20200225.112934-316.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-20200225.112934-316.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-20200225.112934-316.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-20200225.112934-316.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-20200225.112934-316.jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at ubx.hub.streams.StreamsApplication.main(StreamsApplication.java:44) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable]: Factory method 'enriched_toolsTable' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionWrapperSerde.<init>(SubscriptionWrapperSerde.java:31) ~[kafka-streams-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableImpl.doJoinOnForeignKey(KTableImpl.java:956) ~[kafka-streams-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableImpl.leftJoin(KTableImpl.java:891) ~[kafka-streams-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at ubx.hub.streams.StreamsApplication.enriched_toolsTable(StreamsApplication.java:134) [classes/:na]
    at ubx.hub.streams.StreamsApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c0af961.CGLIB$enriched_toolsTable$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at ubx.hub.streams.StreamsApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c0af961$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8469ed4.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-121.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at ubx.hub.streams.StreamsApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c0af961.enriched_toolsTable(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.BUILD-20200225.100750-119.jar:5.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

EDIT : about the foreignKey join bug mentionned by Matthias J. Sax (KAFKA-9517), the join has been changed to

```
        SpecificAvroSerde<ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Key> kSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Key>();
        SpecificAvroSerde<ficexp1.ficexp.tools.enriched> vSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<ficexp1.ficexp.tools.enriched>();
        Materialized materialized =
                Materialized.as("toto").withValueSerde( (Serde) vSerde)
                        .withKeySerde( (Serde) kSerde );
        KTable<ficexp1.ficexp.tools.Key, ficexp1.ficexp.tools.enriched> enrichedToolTable = toolsTable.join(
                tools_typesTable,
                foreignKeyExtractor,
                (ValueJoiner) enrichedToolJoiner,
                ( Materialized ) materialized
                );
```

and it leads to the same error

Comment: Maybe you hit: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9517

Comment: I think it is indeed related so I added a Materialized to the join and I still have the same error

Comment: Couple of bugs are fixed in upcoming 2.4.1 -- maybe build from 2.4 branch or wait for the release?

Comment: Thank you. I hope 2.4.1 will be out soon.